# Leaflet.js HTML Select not working on mobile devices

Tags: javascript, html, select, mobile, leaflet

I am using something similar to this example. The issue is that it doesn't work on mobile devices. In fact, no select seems to work in leaflet.js when its added as a control or part of a control. I am looking for a solution to fix this.

```
var legend = L.control({position: 'topright'});
legend.onAdd = function (map) {
    var div = L.DomUtil.create('div', 'info legend');
    div.innerHTML = '<select><option>1</option><option>2</option><option>3</option></select>';
    div.firstChild.onmousedown = div.firstChild.ondblclick = L.DomEvent.stopPropagation;
    return div;
};
legend.addTo(map);
```

This fiddle is close. However, it using an old version of leaflet and works in mobile devices. Testing with newer libraries doesnt work.
http://jsfiddle.net/nFLc3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add

```
L.DomEvent.disableClickPropagation(div);
```

That seems to allow it to work once that is added.

Comment: Can you explain a bit? I am stuck on the same problem. Didn't solved for my case